# How to map UVs to Cube without small offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, texture-mapping

I am currently making a clone of Minecraft. When I map UV coordinates to a cube there seems to be a small offset. (The small white lines)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It looks to me like the glass texture is seen on the right side on the grass block.

The code which generates the UVs is:

```
    public static readonly int TextureAtlasBlockWidth = 16;
    public static float NormalizedTextureWidth = 1f / (float)TextureAtlasBlockWidth;

    private void AddTexture(int atlasIndex) // atlasIndex is the index of the texture (Stone=0)
    {
        float y = atlasIndex / TextureAtlasBlockWidth;
        float x = atlasIndex - (y * TextureAtlasBlockWidth);

        x *= NormalizedTextureWidth;
        y *= NormalizedTextureWidth;
        y = 1f - y - NormalizedTextureWidth;

        uvs.Add(new Vector2(x, y));
        uvs.Add(new Vector2(x, y + NormalizedTextureWidth));
        uvs.Add(new Vector2(x + NormalizedTextureWidth, y));
        uvs.Add(new Vector2(x + NormalizedTextureWidth, y + NormalizedTextureWidth));
    }
```

I have followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h66IN1Pndd0&list=PLVsTSlfj0qsWEJ-5eMtXsYp03Y9yF1dEn&index=1

And all the code from my project can be found here: https://github.com/theodor349/Minecraft-Clone/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/Chunk.cs

Comment: The problem is called "Texture bleeding". A simple fix would be to make the textures 20x20 (just repeat the "border-pixels" out 2px on each side) but only use the inner 16x16px. Another option would be to use `Point (no filter)` as Filter Mode and disable MipMaps.

Comment: @yes setting it to `Point (Nofilter)` and turning off MipMaps does not work. And I can't seem to make the other method work.

Comment: @yes so I got the padding to work, thanks